# Internal microphone only works when Siri is activated - MacOS 10.13.2

Tags: macos, audio, siri, microphone

https://imgur.com/a/jNpvW (video of the bug)

Internal microphone works only when Siri is activated.
I started noticing this after installing [Boom 2](http://www.globaldelight.com/boom/index.php) (I think), which I've uninstalled now and the problem still persists. I've tried restarting, creating a new user, resetting PRAM, and resetting SMC.
I've also tried messing around with the Audio MIDI Setup.

I've noticed something interesting there which might be relevant. I tried muting the microphone and activating Siri, the microphone is automatically unmuted when Siri is activated and re-muted when Siri is deactivated.

Comment: Did you uninstall Boom using the app's own uninstaller? Otherwise it's not a complete uninstall.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, I used the uninstaller provided by Boom.

Comment: OK, just in case, I'd maybe double-check it got all the bits - Boom is notorious for messing up Mac audio - https://superuser.com/questions/868637/how-can-i-delete-the-boom-application-output-device-from-my-system

Comment: I followed the steps there, still no change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue by activating the dictation functionality. You can find it on "System Settings" > "Keyboard".